# How to keep image with Ken Burns effect in bigger size?

Tags: css

I am using Ken Burns effect on image. It runs very well, the image is going bigger to 1.2 scale. But after animation the image will return to 1.0 scale. How to make it to stay in 1.2 scale?

I am sending a code below how my Ken Burns works.

Thank you.

```css
.logopartner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  animation: move 80s ease;
  /* Add infinite to loop. */
  
  -ms-animation: move 20s ease;
  -webkit-animation: move 20s ease;
  -0-animation: move 20s ease;
  -moz-animation: move 20s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    /* IE 9 */
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    /* Opera */
    
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    /* Firefox */
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    /* IE 9 */
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    /* Opera */
    
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    /* Firefox */
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="logopartner" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scale to 1.2 by default so its final destination is its default scale.

```css
.logopartner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  animation: move 80s ease;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  /* Add infinite to loop. */
  
  -ms-animation: move 20s ease;
  -webkit-animation: move 20s ease;
  -0-animation: move 20s ease;
  -moz-animation: move 20s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    /* IE 9 */
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    /* Opera */
    
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    /* Firefox */
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    /* IE 9 */
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    /* Opera */
    
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    /* Firefox */
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="logopartner" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
```